# How to give Weightage to less than target high pts

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Target of 0.3% Unhappy. If a team achieves 1.2% then it's bad, if a team achieves 0.2% it's good.

On this I have to give weightage of 10 to the team:

```
UH      ACH     %ACH
0.30%   0.20%   67%
0.30%   0.10%   33%
0.30%   1.20%   400%
0.30%   0.29%   97%
```

On the % ach I have to give 10 weightage, if I do so who has less than the target should get good score. How to do so?

I'm not able to get the following result:

```
UH      ACH     %ACH  Result
0.30%   0.20%   67%   9
0.30%   0.10%   33%   10
0.30%   1.20%   400%  5
0.30%   0.29%   97%   8
```

Comment: The scale changes 10 for 33%,9 for 67%, 8 for 97% come to ~1 point off for every 33% but suddenly 400% is 5, it should be -1 on the same scale.  you need to have a set rule for the points not an arbitrary rate.

Comment: Or if it does not follow a patter one would need to create a table with the thresholds and the result desired.  Then one can use a vlookup to return the result.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't provide enough information.

However, if I guess that you want to provide a 10 to the best score (33%) and a 5 to the worst (400%), and we use a linear function for the result in between, you'd be looking at a formula like the following:

I count on column %ACH be column C of the spreadsheet and this formula for cell D2:

```
=(5*C2+5*MIN(C:C)-10*MAX(C:C))/(MIN(C:C)-MAX(C:C))
```